# How to allocate memory to an char array, how to use pointers for that?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

As described above I happen to have a problem with allocating memory for my char array. The point of allocating memory is that I want to  read a .txt file and save all of it in an char array to later work with it. (Looking for the biggest duplicate string)

I' ve looked for over 2 hours now on the internet before posting but I just can't get it working it seems like I am missing something or just don't completely understand how pointers work which I really don't.

The comments are german like some of the variables I hope noone minds that.

Here is the code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <ctype.h>

# define N 99
# define K 255


main() {

FILE *Test;
long len = 1;
int i = 0;
int k;
// char String[N];          //[100][255] = {" "};
// char* pString;
// pString = String;




Test = fopen("Moby_Dick.txt", "r"); // Datei öffnen, r = lesen | (nicht vergessen DATEINAMEN anzupassen)

    if (fseek(Test, 0L, SEEK_END) != 0) {       //jump ans Ende

        printf("\nFEHLER in SEEK_END");
        fclose(Test);
        return 3;
    }

    if ((len = ftell(Test)) < 0L) {

        printf("\nERROR in ftell");
        fclose(Test);
        return 3;
    }

    if (fseek(Test, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) { // jump an den Anfang

        printf("\nERROR in SEEK_SET");
        fclose(Test);
        return 3;
    }

    char *String = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len + 12); //(char*)

    Test = fopen("Eingabe.txt", "r");

    do{
    fgets(String[i], 500, Test); // jede Zeile wird in einem Feld gespeichert
    i++; // zählt die Zeilen hoch 
    }while(!feof(Test)); // lese bis Dateiende

    fclose(Test); // Datei schliessen

     for (k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
     printf("%s\n----------------------------\n", String[k]);
     }
    printf("len = %d\n", len);


return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help I can get. I would love an explanation instead of just passing the code over.

Comment: Thanks for including your code with your question. What exactly do you need help with? Are you getting a particular error, and if so, what is the error? Or, if the program is not giving an error but instead doesn't give the results you're expecting, then what results are you expecting and what did you get instead?

Comment: I want to find the longest duplicate String from a .txt file. I know I need to allocate memory in order to read the file and save it in like an array for example.(don't know what's best in this situation)

Answer (score 2):

After allocating the array, you can read the entire file in a single function call:

```
FILE* file = fopen("Moby_Dick.txt","rt");

fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
int size = ftell(file);
fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);

char* string = (char*)malloc(size+1);
fread(string,size,1,file);
fclose(file);

string[size] = 0;
printf("%s",string);
free(string);
```

Comment: P.S.: my guess is that your `string` did not end with a 0 character...

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas

1. Using `ftell()/fseek()` is *not* a portable nor great way of finding the length of a file.  To fix would require significant work here.  For now, let it be, but know better methods exist.
2. The cast of `malloc()` results is not needed.  The extra 12 bytes is arbitrary and not needed.  `sizeof(char)` is always 1.  If anyhting use `sizeof(*String)`.

   ```
   // char *String = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 12); //(char*)
   char *String = malloc(len * sizeof(*String));
   // or
   char *String = malloc(len);
   ```
3. The loop `do{ fgets(String[i] ... while(!feof(Test));` has many problems.  Better to do something suggested by @barak manos

   ```
   // fgets(String[i], 500, Test);
   if (1 != fread(string,size,1,file)) {
     Handle_Readfailure();
   }
   ```
4. Match your format

   ```
   // printf("len = %d\n", len);
   printf("len = %ld\n", len);
   ```
5. But having addressed the above minor issues, the approach could improve.  Your goal:

> read a .txt file and save all of it .. to later work with it. (Looking for the biggest duplicate string)

To accomplish this suggest:

1. Read each *line* of text.
2. Walk through list looking for "biggest duplicate".

The below is not tested, and is missing some error handling.  There is room for performance improvements.  But it does not depend on `Test` being a file, it could be a stream like `stdin`.  Need to add `free()`-ing the buffers.   It does assume a maximum line length of 1024;

```
// Read lines
size_t LineCount = 0;
size_t LineSize = 0;
char **Line = NULL;
char buffer[1024];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, Test) != NULL) {
  if (LineCount >= LineSize) {
    LineSize = LineSize*2 + 1;
    Line = realloc(Line, LineSize * sizeof(*Line)); // TBD error handling
  }
  size_t len = strlen(buffer);
  if (len > 0 && buffer[len - 1] == '\n') buffer[--len] = '\0';
  len++;
  Line[LineCount] = malloc(len);
  memcpy(Line[LineCount], buffer, len);
  LineCount++;
}
fclose(Test);

// search lines
size_t Longest = 0;
size_t Index = 0;
for (size_t i=0; i<LineCount; i++) {
  size_t leni = strlen(Line[i]) + 1;
  if (leni <= Longest) continue; // line too short to beat the best.
  for (size_t j=0; j<i; j++) {
    if (strcmp(Line[i], Line[j]) == 0) {  // duplicate found
      Longest = leni;
      Index = i;
      break;// skip checking Line[i] against Line[j+1] to Line[i-1]
    }
  }
}

if (Longest > 0) {
  printf("Longest duplicate line is \"%s\".\n", Line[Index]);
}
else {
  printf("No duplicates found.\n");
}
```

Comment: size_t doesn't seem to work. I am useing only C not C++ is there something I might overlook? I have added the "# include <stddef.h>".

Comment: NVM, size_t works correctly, the program just doesn't do anything after adding the libraries and fopen. And I don't understand why.

Comment: @user3195768 `size_t` is in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as you have found.  Concerning "doesn't do anything", suggest sprinkling `printf()` statements in your code or better yet, use a debugger to step and breakpoint through your code.  My posted code replaces your code starting at `do{`.